# Add a line leading space after first pattern and just above next pattern using SED/AWK

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Input:

define {
   abcd **pattern**
   xyzs wedlenle
   jqwd sadjkjnd 
}

define {
   abcd asjdanja
   xyzs wedlenle
   jqwd sadjkjnd 
}

define {
   adkja **pattern**
   xyzs wedlenle
   jqwd sadjkjnd 
}

expected output:

define {
   abcd **pattern**
   xyzs wedlenle
   jqwd sadjkjnd 
   **addtext**

}

define {
   abcd asjdanja
   xyzs wedlenle
   jqwd sadjkjnd

}

define {
   adkja **pattern**
   xyzs wedlenle
   **addtext**

}

Need to add line(leading space) in same define block just before "}".

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk '
/pattern/ { f=1 }
/}/ {
    if (f) {
        sub(/[^[:space:]].*/,"",last)
        print last "addtext"
        f=0
    }
}
{ print }
NF { last = $0 }
' file
define {

       abcd **pattern**
       xyzs wedlenle
       jqwd sadjkjnd


       addtext
}

define {

       abcd asjdanja
       xyzs wedlenle
       jqwd sadjkjnd


}

define {

       adkja **pattern**
       xyzs wedlenle
       jqwd sadjkjnd


       addtext
}
```

I'm not convinced all those trailing blank lines exist in your real input file which is why I've put no effort into dealing with them in this answer.

Comment: Thank you so much Ed.Just need to remove extra blank new line above "addtext".Can you help me with that?

Comment: You're welcome but the script does not add an extra blank line above "addtext". Do you want all blank lines removed? If not, why not? If so, just change `{ print } NF { last = $0 }` to `NF { print; last = $0 }`.

Comment: Ed, I want to use while loop for several pattern.Can you help me how to define pattern as variable for awk ?

Comment: `awk -v pat="pattern" '$0 ~ pat { f=1 } ...`. It's extremely unlikely that a while loop is a good idea though, you can probably do everything you want in a single call to awk. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: yes you are right. I am finding difficulty while managing loop and i will certainly try with single call.However, at this moment can you tell me how to make changes(addtext) to the "same file" instead of  print ??[in my case file become black while loop iteration...] appreciate your quick response.

Comment: With **ANY** tool, to change the original file is `tool file > tmp && mv tmp file` so in  this case `awk 'script' file > tmp && mv tmp file`. GNU awk 4.0 and later as an option for "inplace editing" which would be `awk -i inplace 'script' file` but that just uses a tmp file behind the scenes.

Comment: I have already tried using tmp file.while read -r pattern; do 'script' > tmp && mv tmp file; done < List_pattern_file. Doubts: 1) last pattern in the file is not affected not sure if you can find any iteration issue in while loop. 2)  Can you suggest little tweak in script so it verify that addtext is not already exist in same define block ?  Thank you so much for all help !

Comment: Post a new question, you're veering very far from the question you posted.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39580660/add-a-line-after-first-pattern-and-last-pattern-only-if-that-line-not-exist-in-b