# Add text between patterns using AWK

Tags: awk

INPUT:

```
Define {
     abcd **pattern**
     xyzs wedlenle
     jqwd sadjkjnd 
} 
Define { 
     abcd asjdanja
     xyzs wedlenle
     jqwd sadjkjnd
}
Define {
     abcd **pattern**
     xyzs wedlenle
     jqwd sadjkjnd 
     ADD LINE HERE
}
```

Expected OUTPUT:

```
Define {
     abcd **pattern**
     xyzs wedlenle
     jqwd sadjkjnd 
     ADD LINE HERE
} 
Define { 
     abcd asjdanja
     xyzs wedlenle
     jqwd sadjkjnd
}
Define {
     abcd **pattern**
     xyzs wedlenle
     jqwd sadjkjnd 
     ADD LINE HERE
}
```

Need to **ADD LINE ** define block just before "}".

Corner case:
1) Multiple pattern - used while loop
2) Added line should be leading with space
3) Only add line if it not exist alreday in same block.

Comment: @Ed Morton Can you please help me out ?Thanks

Comment: Please show expected output first. I'm sure Ed would appreciate it.

Comment: @james Input : without "ADD LINE HERE" Output: with "ADD LINE HERE" as pattern exist in first block.I want to make sure that it wont duplicate line in same block.

Comment: [edit] your question to show a [mcve] including concise, testable sample input AN output plus what you have tried so far. Make sure your use of white space is accurate, show the worst case you need to handle, not just any old sunny day case, and use the editor's `{}` button to properly format your input, output, and code.

Comment: @EdMorton Updated my question.Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: Your text is talking about multiple patterns and not adding text when already present but none of those cases are represented in  your sample input/output. Try again and this time create input/output that truly represents all of your use cases.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat test.awk
BEGIN {
    RS=ORS="}"
} 
{   # BELOW         don't print:       print:
    print $0 ($0 !~ /ADD LINE/ && $0 ~ /PATTERN/? "     ADD LINE HERE\n" :"")
}
```

Test file:

```
$ cat > test.txt
Define {
     has PATTERN
     no add line
     so add it here
} 
Define {
     has PATTERN
     has ADD LINE
     dont add it here
} 
Define { 
     no pattern
     no add line
     dont add it here
}
```

Test run:

```
$ awk -f test.awk test.txt
Define {
     has PATTERN
     no add line
     so add it here
     ADD LINE HERE
} 
Define {
     has PATTERN
     has ADD LINE
     dont add it here
} 
Define { 
     no pattern
     no add line
     dont add it here
}
```

Comment: while IFS= read -r line; do
awk -v pat="$line" '$0 ~ pat { f=1 }
/}/ {
    if (f) {
        sub(/[^[:space:]].*/,"",last)
        print last "addtext"
        f=0
    }
}
NF {print; last = $0 }
' file

done <input line file

Comment: I have mutiple pattern and need to manage leading space, above script working competely fine.Only i need help regarding validating that " add text" is already there or not in same block and only add to it if not exist.

Comment: @RajenPatel what are you trying to do with that shell `while` loop in your comment? It's not needed for the example in your question and is a bad idea in general (see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)). If the sample input/output in your question doesn't accurately represent your real needs then edit your question so they do but this is your 2nd attempt to ask your question so put some effort into getting it right this time.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '
/}/ {
    if (f) {
        sub(/[^[:space:]].*/,"",prev)
        print prev "ADD LINE HERE"
        f=0
    }
}
/pattern/ { f=1 }
{ prev=$0; print }
' file
Define {
     abcd **pattern**
     xyzs wedlenle
     jqwd sadjkjnd
     ADD LINE HERE
}
Define {
     abcd asjdanja
     xyzs wedlenle
     jqwd sadjkjnd
}
```

Comment: It adds "ADD LINE HERE" each time when run above script.I want to make sure line wont duplicated in same block.

Comment: Read the comments you already have and then try one last time to post an accurate question. The important thing you are missing is that your posted sample input/output simply does not cover your use cases so a script that produces the output you say you expect given the input you provided doesn't actually do what you seem to want.